# Отличие запроса с подзапросом и операции соединения MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Изучаю MySQL. У меня возник вопрос, чем отличаются запросы, составленнные с подзапросом от запросом с использованием операции соединения таблиц.
Привожу листинг:
1 вариант с подзапросом:

```
mysql> select fio
-> from persons
-> where person_id in (select person from film_creators
-> where film in (select film_id from films
-> where film_name = 'Сталкер'));
```

2 вариант с использованием операции соединения таблиц:

```
mysql> select fio
-> from persons
-> where person_id in (select distinct person
-> from film_creators, films
-> where film_creators.film = films.film_id and films.film_name = 'Сталкер');
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, какой из запросов будет более эффективен или какие-либо другие отличия. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: У меня комментарий по оформлению вопроса. Рекомендую вам в будущем писать запросы на so приводя только их текст, без этих `->`: большинство их потом вставляет в IDE и эти стрелки только мешают выполнению кода. Отвлекаться на них и убирать? Экономьте чужое время потенциально неограниченного числа лиц. В качестве образца, чтобы далеко не ходить - посмотрите ответ Антона или Марка.

Comment: Оптимизаторы в СУБД настолько загадочны, что как только встает вопрос оптимизации надо оценивать все подходящие варианты с помощью explain. причем никто не гарантирует что в следующей версии MySQL будет себя вести так же как в предыдущей. в общем виде первый запрос выглядит хорошим вариантом. Но это слишком простой случай, с очень большой вероятностью во всех случаях оптимизатор даст одинаковый план выполнения. Различия видны когда ожидается получить довольно много строк, точнее когда оптимизатор может подумать. что их будет много

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас подзапросы используются в обоих примерах, между тем, можно написать запрос только с соединениями.

Во-первых, сначала построим запрос, который извлечёт нужный фильм:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM films
 WHERE films.film_name = 'Сталкер'
```

Нам нужны люди, создавшие этот фильм. Поскольку между людьми и фильмами связь многие-ко-многим, нам нужна промежуточная таблица `film_creators`:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM films
  JOIN film_creators ON film_creators.film = films.film_id
  JOIN persons ON person.person_id = film_creator.person
 WHERE films.film_name = 'Сталкер'
```

В данном случае у нас используется два *внутренних* соединения, то есть мы получим список только тех людей, для которых есть запись в `film_creators`.

Возможно, таблица `film_creators` содержит поле, которое показывает *должность* человека, например, *режиссёр* или *сценарист*. Тогда один и тот же человек может появиться в списке несколько раз. Здесь мы можем использовать `DISTINCT`. Нам нужны только ФИО, поэтому полный запрос примет вид:

```
SELECT DISTINCT person.fio
  FROM films
  JOIN film_creators ON film_creators.film = films.film_id
  JOIN persons ON person.person_id = film_creator.person
 WHERE films.film_name = 'Сталкер'
```

Либо мы можем показать имя несколько раз вместе с должностью:

```
SELECT person.fio, film_creators.position
  FROM films
  JOIN film_creators ON film_creators.film = films.film_id
  JOIN persons ON person.person_id = film_creator.person
 WHERE films.film_name = 'Сталкер'
```

Теперь по поводу эффективности. Важнейшим качеством кода является его простота, а не его эффективность. Опыт учит нас, что делать код эффективным нужно только после того, как доказана его неэффективность. Поэтому план работы всегда один: сначала вы пишете работающий код, потом упрощаете так, чтобы с ним мог работать другой человек или вы через полгода. Наконец, вы пишете нагрузочный тест и смотрите, устраивает ли вас скорость. Если скорость вас не устраивает, вы переписываете код так, чтобы он работал быстро. В этот момент можно пожертвовать ясностью кода, написав подробный комментарий, почему здесь сделано именно так.

Здесь спасает знание принципов работы реляционных СУБД, в частности, понимание того, как происходит поиск в упорядоченном массиве по составному ключу. В таком случае вы можете просто на основе анализа запросов правильно расставить индексы. Текст запросов при этом менять совсем не нужно.

Но если индексы не помогают, то следующим шагом является использование планировщика запросов и перебор вариантов синтаксиса. Что-то может и помочь.

В общем и целом синтаксис с соединениями проще для чтения и понимания, чем синтаксис с подзапросами, поэтому, если логика позволяет, лучше ограничиться соединениями. Если не позволяет, делайте код с подзапросом.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте перед `SELECT` `EXPLAIN` и смотрите, что эффективнее. Я подозреваю, что самым эффективным будет такой запрос

```
select
  persons.fio
from
  films
  LEFT JOIN film_creators ON (
    film_creators.film = films.film_id
  )
  JOIN persons ON (
    persons.person_id = film_creators.person
  )
where
  films.film_name = 'Сталкер' AND
  persons.person_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Мы выбираем конкретный `films` с конкретным именем. Т.е. сразу отсеиваем 99% записей

Comment: да, перепутал. но LEFT у persons явный перебор.

Comment: @Mike Почему?..

Comment: потому что условие в where ему явно противоречит. У оптимизатора oracle до 10 версии от такого бы крышу конкретно снесло. У MySQL крышу не сносит, он начисто игнорирует слово LEFT в таких случаях.